# Qt - How does this center the window

Tags: qt, position, center

I saw an example that uses the following to create a point that will be used to centre a window in `Qt`:

> x = (screenWidth - WIDTH) / 2;
>
> y = (screenHeight - HEIGHT) / 2;

Provided that `screenWidth` and `screenHeight` are found using the `width()` and `height()` functions respectively of `QDesktopWidget`.

How does the preceding code centre the window? Yes, I know it centres the window, but couldn't understand it from a calculation point of view.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First calculate the total amount of 'extra' horizontal space around your window:

```
extra_space = screenWidth - your_window_width
```

now, spread that space at left and right:

```
left_space + right_space = extra_space
```

the space at both sides should be the same:

```
right_space = left_space
==>  2 * left_space = extra_space
==>  2 * left_space = screenWidth - your_window_width
==>  left_space = (screenWidth - your_window_width) / 2
```

that's your `x`.   The same goes for the `y` coordinate.